# What does sqlite3_close failed 27 mean?

Tags: android, sqlite

I get the following error when closing a sqlite database:
02-22 15:42:03.184: ERROR/SqliteDatabaseCpp(846): sqlite3_close(0x1ca0c0) failed: 27

What does it mean?

Comment: It means that it couldn't close the database.

Comment: yeah - ok. but why couldn't it close the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically I'd tell you to go looking [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html), but happens as it may - the error code you are getting (`27`) happens to be a special little something added *specifically* for Android.

More explictly, it's defined like this:

```
define SQLITE_UNCLOSED    27   /* db can't be closed due unfinalized stmts */
```

Basically, this means you have crap that you have not yet called `#close()` on - any prepared statements or similar perhaps (or InsertHelpers - they use them to).

Comment: This is the right answer.
It turns out that after accessing the database table using a cursor then the cursor needs to closed using cursor.close()

Answer (score 0):

Either because it has already been stopped before or some thread / code is communicating with the database. I would think the 1st is the one.