# sqlite3_close failed 27

Tags: android-sqlite

I'm getting this "sqlite3_close(0x1f7f708) failed: 27" error sometimes and I can0t understand why. Here is my code:

```
    xMessage[] msgs = new xMessage[howMany];
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor, cursorData = null;

    cursor = db.query(mail_bridge_table_name, new String[] {mbfn_mbridge_PK, mbfn_mdata_FK, mbfn_contacts, mbfn_subject, mbfn_sentTime, mbfn_receivedTime, mbfn_maccount_FK }, null,
              null, null, null, mbfn_sentTime + " desc", first + "," + howMany);

    if (cursor != null)
          cursor.moveToFirst();
    else
    {
        msgs[0] = new xMessage();
        msgs[0].set_bodyPlain("Mail data not found!");
        return msgs;
    }
    long count = cursor.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
             [omissis: db unrelated code....]

        cursorData = db.query(mail_data_table_name, new String[] {mdfn_mdata_PK, mdfn_header, mdfn_body }, mdfn_mdata_PK + "=?",
                  new String[]{cursor.getString(mbfi_mdata_FK)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursorData != null)
        {
            cursorData.moveToFirst();
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    if (cursor != null)
    {
        cursor.close();
    }
    if (cursorData != null)
    {
        cursorData.close();
    }
    db.close();    <----- here I get sometime the error
    return msgs;
```

I have another thread working with the same database, but I get the error even stopping it. I had a look around and I have found on the forum that the failed: 27 lasts for a try to close a db with some action still open...but I just open two cursors that I close.

anyone can help? I'm stack on this problem since 2 days..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is the answer. [What does sqlite3_close failed 27 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398123/what-does-sqlite3-close-failed-27-mean). It is basically means there are statements have not called close().